# Why don't identity providers have separate IDs and Names in Openstack?

Tags: openstack, saml, identity-management, openstack-keystone, uniqueidentifier

I think most of the things have a separate ID and a separate Name in Openstack (Users, Projects, virtual machines, etc). Why don't identity providers have separate IDs and Names? Are there other objects like this? Is there a rule why specific entities must have both IDs and Names while others can live without a separate Name?

```
$ openstack identity provider list
+----------------+---------+-------------+
| ID             | Enabled | Description |
+----------------+---------+-------------+
| cloud1         | True    | None        |
+----------------+---------+-------------+
```